# WSO2IS with Kerberos/IWA/SPNEGO authentication

Tags: kerberos, saml, windows-authentication, spnego, wso2-identity-server

According to https://docs.wso2.org/display/IS460/Enabling+IWA+in+WSO2+Identity+Server IS seems to be configured to use WAFFLE which can be used only on Windows.

Did anyone have a chance to successfully install using http://spnego.sourceforge.net/ framework?

It would be appreciated to not limit the environment to Windows only.

Comment: Tomcat has a built-in Kerberos module (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html), which relies on JGSS implementation in JVM. On Linux you may use Oracle JVM with a really great JGSS - very well tested and mature.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Tomcat, you can simply use my library: http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The http://spnego.sf.net/ works fine on Tomcat7, but the problem located in the integration of WSO2.

Answer (score 0):

We have managed to create a custom authenticator where

- the authenticator redirects user to a page hosted in Tomcat ([Custom logon page](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Customizing+Login+Pages)
- the logon page doesn't display any logon form, but using the [Tomcat SPNEGO](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/) user is authenticated with SPNEGO / Kerberos and a JWT ticket is posted back to the authenticator (commonAuthId) instead of username and password
- the authenticator assumes identity of the user (set the username in the authentication context)

This is de facto a custom claim authentication, do not forget to sign / validate the posted ticket.